# How to specify static file path in Android NDK?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-ndk, static-libraries

I need to create a dynamic library in `Android.mk`.

Say I have the following files

```
/home/name/android/Android.mk
/home/name/android/lib/share/libfile.so
```

How should I modify the `Android.mk`?

Comment: Ok, No Downvote, will you upload code please.

Comment: @Lucifer,I remember only a line of code,but I forgot it.

Comment: Well, i asked to code, because it helps to understand question better, no hardfeelings :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS = -L$(LOCAL_PATH)lib/share -lfile
```

you can try it

Answer (score 0):

I didnt quite understand your question but I hope this is what you are asking for, This Android make file includes static prebuilt library.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mylib.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myfile.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := myfile.h


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := mylib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

To include dynamic library you can modify to PREBUILT_DYNAMIC_LIBRARY